# Can't change my screen resolution on Esprimo Mobile v5535

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, sis-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 in my old Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile v5535, but i think the graphics card driver is not installed with, because whenever i open a window, I can't see the whole thing. For example, when I google something, I can't see the research results properly, as everything is just huge. I tried to change the resolution but the only option is 640x480. Can somenone help me fixing this?

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: I am on an answer. It is SiS. I have this laptop. Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a driver, but you will need to downgrade the graphical stack to support the driver.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-all
```

You will be asked to agree to remove lots of packages and install lots too. You will need to agree with that.

Reboot.

If the procedure was OK, then proceed. You will need to install some packages and build the driver.

Run in terminal (one-by-one).

```
sudo apt-get install git xorg-dev mesa-common-dev libdrm-dev libtool build-essential
sudo apt-get install x11proto-xf86dga-dev x11proto-xf86dri-dev x11proto-gl-dev libxext-dev
git clone git://github.com/hellnest/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1.git
cd xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static
sudo make install
```

Reboot again. You will be able to set 1280x800 resolution.

There may be issues with running videos. If you meet any, let me know. I will try to remember how they are fixed.

Don't be worried with funny things happening with the splash screen with Ubuntu logo at boot and shutdown. It is OK.

Do not upgrade the system to 14.04. There is no way to get the graphics adapter work properly on new Ubuntu versions.

You may also meet a problem with video playback. In this case run

```
gstreamer-properties
```

and switch output to `X11`.

If you are using VLC, you will need to switch output in VLC settings.

Comment: It worked perfectyl! I am really grateful for your help!! :D  By the way, whenever a reinstalled windows xp in this laptop, i had to install a lot of drivers all by myself, to make the computer work properly, but with Ubuntu, everything seems just fine. Do you know if i need to install other drivers?

Comment: You do not need any other drivers for this laptop. Everything works well.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aquainted with this forums. If there is somethig else I might do, like give you a ''point'' or else (I don't know how this works) let me know :)

Comment: You've done everything correctly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this solved me:
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub 
;uncomment the line;
 #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 to p.ex.
 GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768 
;save and;
 sudo update-grub 
;on next boot you'll have the desired screen resolution

Comment: This is not the "desired" resolution but 1024x768.