# Installing Ubuntu 17.04 on FS Esprimo Mobile V5535 (Graphics card problem)

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have an old Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile V5535, over the past 8 years I tried many times to install the latest Ubuntu version on it but I always had the same problem, the graphics card driver is not available and the screen resolution is too small and whenever I try to play a video Ubuntu freezes.

About a week ago I read a topic about a solution to install the driver, but they said it only works for versions before 14.04. But I want to install 17.04 is there a way to do it? and how to play videos without UBUNTU freezing?

Please help ASAP. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the link with the supposed fix?

Comment: Sure
https://askubuntu.com/questions/803093/cant-change-my-screen-resolution-on-esprimo-mobile-v5535

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803093/cant-change-my-screen-resolution-on-esprimo-mobile-v5535

Answer (score 1):

The SiS graphics adapter installed in that laptop is obsolete. It is not supported by modern Xorg drivers because of hardware limitations.

I have this laptop. You can't use any modern OS on it including Windows. The last Windows version that works with normal screen resolution is Vista.

So there is no way to get a proper screen resolution on this laptop with any new Ubuntu release. The last one that worked was 12.04.2, or 12.04.1.

You can use 12.04, or use this laptop as a server, router, etc. with a new version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks alot.

I will use 12.04, it is 5 years old but it is still better looking than windows :D